Можно ли описать свой класс так, чтобы при обращении к его экземплярам они что-то возвращали?
Можно ли описать свой класс так, чтобы при вызове его экземпляров они что-то возвращали?
Пример:
class A {...};

int main() {
    A a(10);
    std::cout << a; // 10
}


Такой штуки как "вызов экземпляров" в С++ нет. В std::cout << a; вызывается бинарный оператор <<, перегрузите его для вашего класса, если хотите, чтобы тут что-то выводилось.

Вообще-то "вызов его экземпляров" — это a(), а это — без проблем :)

Вопрос в том, чтобы сделать универсальную реализацию, которая позволит при каждом обращении к объекту, обращаться например к какому-либо его полю.

Еще раз: При обращении к объекту в С++ происходит только обращение к объекту. Чтобы что-то с ним сделать придется вызвать либо его метод, либо оператор. Чтобы обратиться к его полю, придется обращаться к полю явно. @Harry Ну нет, a() это все-таки не "вызов экземпляра", а вызов перегруженного оператора ().

Можно перегрузить << для вашего класса.
Можно перегрузить оператор преобразования:
class A
{
  public:
    int x;
    operator int() const {return x;}
};

